# How to drop MongoDB collection after test using spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, junit4, morphia

This is my xml:

```
    <bean class="java.lang.String" id="mongoDbTest">
        <constructor-arg value="Test" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.mongodb.MongoClient" id="mongo" />
    <bean class="org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia" id="morphia" />
```

My DAOs bean is getting mongo and morphia in the constructors.
I would like to have a test class that using the DAO to save and assert some entities in the DB.
After each test i would like to clean the DB from records.

Is there any xml attribute that i would be able to use?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can change name of the database for tests, and on the end of the test drop it.

But I can recommend you to use [Embedded MongoDB](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo). "Embedded MongoDB will provide a platform neutral way for running mongodb in unittests."

It's very simple to use. It creates mongoDB database in-memory. You can find tutorial [here](http://dontpanic.42.nl/2015/02/in-memory-mongodb-for-unit-and.html).